# NPC keeps walking into walls - Unity2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision

My NPCs have collision detection by void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) and by raycast in case something is ahead, but occasionally they get stuck trying to reach their randomly generated destination through the obstacles. Any ideas why it's happening? Here's the code:

collisions:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    if (col.collider == playerCollider)
    {
       // Code
    }

    else
    {
        regenDestination();
    }
}
```

raycast

```
void throwRaycast()
{
    RaycastHit2D hitInfo = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, randomDestination, raycastDistance);
    Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, randomDestination, Color.red);
    if (hitInfo.collider != null)
    {
        regenDestination();
    }
}
```

destination change

```
void regenDestination()
{
    randomDestination = new Vector2(Random.Range(-11, 11), Random.Range(-5, 5));
    GoToLocation();
}
```

Comment: You might want to use a [NavMeshAgent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMeshAgent.html) instead.

Comment: HOLY MOLLY I didn't know there is such feature, thank you sooo much!